# Codaset: can't do initial push!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, github, codaset

For people who use Codaset...

I can't push! :(  My application is recently added, and this is what git push origin yields:

`error: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
 while accessing https://codaset.com/daze/rampage.git/info/refs`

fatal: HTTP request failed

I already added the origin as my remote, so git remote -v yields:

`origin https://codaset.com/daze/rampage.git (fetch)`

origin https://codaset.com/daze/rampage.git (push)

My SSH key is already uploaded, too. Help?

Also...how come there's no clear link to http://codaset.com/account/ssh_keys to view my ssh keys?  Not too intuitive a design...
Hmmm should I just use GitHub instead?  It may be easier...what's better, codaset or github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best place to post this is at http://codaset.com, which it looks like you already have.

To **summarise**, you are trying to push over Smart-HTTPS but are doing so with a version of Git that is older than 1.6.6. Smart-HTTPS support was added in 1.6.6. So upgrade to the latest Git, and all should work for you.